# reload div javascript only ajax needed?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, reload

please refer to JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/s11oo2gg/. 
We are not allowed to use jQuery and iframe here.

The problem right now if you click on resistor first and hover over different content images then come back out by clicking the X mark, the content image would get stucked where you left off and would not load the the other content images properly. It would show a broken image link.

I like to reload only the `<div id="slider1_contain">` everytime I click on  `<span class="closeButton">`(X mark) so the target content images can be loaded accordingly.

I dont not want to have `location.reload();` to resolve this when the X is click. I dont want to reload the whole page but only the div.

I saw people were asking the same question and solve it with AJAX. Do I need AJAX for this case?  Or is there something we can do in the following javascript?

Thank you in advance!!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function showContent(target){
            document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("boxThumb").style.display = 'none';
        }

        function hideContent(target){
        document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("boxThumb").style.display = 'block'

        }
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var children = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle > section[id]');
    function showDetailContent(target) {
    // Simply loop over our children and ensure they are hidden:
    for (var i = 0, child; child = children[i]; i++) {
        child.style.display = 'none';
    }
    // Now, show our child we want to show
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: When the "X" is clicked, what do you want to happen that is not currently happening?  If you're not needing to fetch content from the server, there is no need for Ajax.  You should be able to just hide and show portions of the browser DOM with client-side javascript.  But, I can't really tell from your question what exactly you want help doing.\

Comment: javascript is working as intended. but if you first click into "resister" and hover all three images available then click on "X", then you click into "philips superflux" and it will show a blank page until hovering the thumbnails on the bottom right. I just like it to show the "1stdetailContent" as soon as I click into it, like the default image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload just the div, you can use `innerHTML`.

```
 document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = '<img src="image.jpg">';
```

Comment: im not quite understand, innerHTML is used to text, not HTML content if im not mistaken.